# Game Server suggestions

Tags: client-server, network-protocols, timing

**EDIT**

I'm completely rewriting this since I realized it wasn't very clear what I needed.

So, I'm going to implement an online game. The idea is quite simple. All players have to answer the same set of questions that is downloaded from the server. To answer each question the player has a given amount of time that depends on question difficulty. The questions are presented one at a time. After the time to answer the current question elapses the next one is presented to the player. After the last question the client should display the leaderboard with the scores of all currently online players. The leaderboard is (of course) computed on server and clients should download it when the game finishes.

OK that's the idea. What I require is some suggestions on how to implement the whole client-server communication. I don't need details but just some ideas. Most important I'm not sure how client-server time-sync could work. It's important that all players have the same amount of time to answer each question. I also have a solution that is very simple but I'm not sure about possible pitfalls. What I have in mind is that when the player first connects (or when a new game starts) the client downloads the whole list of questions for current game. Also some time-sync messages are exchanged to get current game time. Then after questions and time-sync are known at the client, a local timer is started and the game runs completely offline. When the game finishes each client sends its own score/result to the server. When the leaderboard is ready the server sends it back to all clients. Once again a local timer could be used to know when a new game is starting and to download the new list of questions.

Please post your suggestions and comment my solution. Thanks

Comment: SO doesn't handle suggestions very well.  You haven't even attempted to resolve this yourself.  I would suggest implementing this in your own manner, and if you get stuck, asking about the problem you're facing.  StackOverflow isn't here to do your research for you.

Comment: That's ok, it's just that I tought this was so simple and "standard" that many people could share some best practices or advices. Anyway, following your suggestion I'll try to do it my way hoping that it works well. In the meanwhile anyone wanting to express his/her opinion is welcome.